# Merge (via moving) two directories and subdirectories, replacing exisiting files (not folders!)

Tags: bash

I have two directories, with the following structure:

```
root_a
- dir_b
-- file
-- file
-- ...
- dir_c
-- file
-- file
-- ...

root_b
- dir_b
-- file
-- file
-- ...
- dir_c
-- file
-- file
-- ...
```

Each subdirectory (i.e., dir_b and dir_c) contain 10s of thousands of files.

I want to merge root_a and _root_b into a target directory, root_c. I.e. I want root_c/dir_b to contain files from both root_a/dir_b and root_b/dir_b, and root_c/dir_c to contain files from both root_a/dir_c and root_b/dir_c.

E.g

```
root_c
- dir_b
-- file (e.g. from root_a/dir_b)
-- file (e.g. from root_b/dir_c)
-- ...
- dir_c
-- file (e.g. from root_a/dir_b)
-- file (e.g. from root_b/dir_c)
-- ...
```

How can I do this?

I tried using bash mv, but this does not work because I have too many files:

```
#!/bin/bash

# check if the number of arguments is correct
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE TARGET"
  exit 1
fi

# set variables for the source and target directories
src=$1
tgt=$2

# move all directories and files from the source to the target, replacing any existing files
mv -f $src/* $tgt
```

Note: I do not want to COPY. I want to MOVE files. I have limited space, and cannot copy and then delete the originals. Plus, that would take a very long time...

Comment: The output you posted contains both files from `root_a/dir_b` and `root_a/dir_c`

Comment: Did you check this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149965/how-to-copy-merge-two-directories

Comment: What if a same filename exists in both directories? For instance, `root_a/dir_b/abc` and `root_b/dir_b/abc`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin then just replace

Comment: @Jetchisel that's the point

Comment: `rsync` should be able to do it though?

Comment: @Fravadona Thanks, in the end I was able to do it with the amazing rsync.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mv` from GNU coreutils:

```
#!/bin/bash

for subdir in dir_b dir_c; do
    find {root_a,root_b}/"$subdir" -type f -exec mv -t root_c/"$subdir" {} +
done
```